# Missing something on our VLAN - Linksys SRW2048 switch

Tags: vlan, linksys

I'm trying to isolate traffic using a VLAN, one of our Linksys SRW2048's and two connections going back to our network from the switch.

Currently I have 3 Vlans, 1 is the default, 2 is for iSCSI, 3 was for General Data.  Everything works fine if I leave it on the default - 1.

If I move a PC and one of the connections back to our network onto 3, that PC can't see anything.  1 continues to talk to the network fine.

Both ports in 3 and I have tried them set as Untagged - Access, Untagged - General, and Tagged - General.

Is there a setting I am missing somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some kind of inter vlan routing set up. Your switch may provide this.  If not a dedicated router would.